# Remove buttons for a few seconds in Python/Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a program where the user will make a selection based on a target image. I'm trying to get the program to remove the selection buttons and wait 2 seconds after updating the target image before the selection choices are re-presented. The code that I have seems to "disable" the clicked button for 2 seconds, but does not remove either button.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")


def click_b(event):
    btn_b.pack_forget()
    btn_c.pack_forget()
    new_a()
    root.update()
    root.after(2000, show_btns())


def click_c(event):
    btn_b.pack_forget()
    btn_c.pack_forget()
    new_a()
    root.update()
    root.after(2000, show_btns())


def new_a():
    k = random.randrange(1, 3)
    if k == 1:
        btn_a.configure(image=a1)
    elif k == 2:
        btn_a.configure(image=a2)


def show_btns():
    btn_b.pack(side=LEFT)
    btn_c.pack(side=RIGHT)

a1 = PhotoImage(file="A1.gif")
a2 = PhotoImage(file="A2.gif")
orange = PhotoImage(file="orange_btn.gif")
green = PhotoImage(file="yellowgreen_btn.gif")
btn_a = Button(root, image=a1)
btn_a.pack()

btn_b = Button(root, image=orange)
btn_b.bind('<Button-1>', click_b)
btn_b.pack(side=LEFT)

btn_c = Button(root, image=green)
btn_c.bind('<Button-1>', click_c)
btn_c.pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you done any research? There are lots of questions on this site about hiding widgets, and probably most tkinter tutorials cover the subject in one way or another.

Comment: I've searched extensively. From everything that I've found the code I have should work. None of the questions that have been asked, that I have been able to find, re-present the widgets - they just remove them.

Comment: Actually this works fine for me... the buttons do disappear.

Comment: @ROAR how odd. I did test the code and got an error when pressing the buttons. Now it seams to work fine when testing the OPs code after your comment...

Comment: @SierraMountainTech well maybe when you changed the code for yourself to work (changed images and stuff) you accidentally changed something else you shouldn't have.

Comment: @ROAR. Thats possible. Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issues is in your `after()` methods.
You need to remove the brackets for the `show_btns` function call or else tkinter will not run this command properly. If you have a function with no arguments you leave off the `()` portion.

If you do have arguments then you will need to either provide those arguments in the after statement IE `after(2000, some_func, arg1, arg2)` or use `lambda` to create a one off function to do the work like `after(2000, lambda: some_func(arg1, arg2))`. lambda can be more complicated but this is the basic concept.

change:

```
after(2000, show_btns())
```

To:

```
after(2000, show_btns)
```

As long as your paths to your images work fine the below code should work as intended.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def click_b(event):
    btn_b.pack_forget()
    btn_c.pack_forget()
    new_a()
    root.update()
    root.after(2000, show_btns)

def click_c(event):
    btn_b.pack_forget()
    btn_c.pack_forget()
    new_a()
    root.update()
    root.after(2000, show_btns)

def new_a():
    k = random.randrange(1, 3)
    if k == 1:
        btn_a.configure(image=a1)
    elif k == 2:
        btn_a.configure(image=a2)

def show_btns():
    btn_b.pack(side=LEFT)
    btn_c.pack(side=RIGHT)

a1 = PhotoImage(file="A1.gif")
a2 = PhotoImage(file="A2.gif")
orange = PhotoImage(file="orange_btn.gif")
green = PhotoImage(file="yellowgreen_btn.gif")
btn_a = Button(root, image=a1)
btn_a.pack()

btn_b = Button(root, image=orange)
btn_b.bind('<Button-1>', click_b)
btn_b.pack(side=LEFT)

btn_c = Button(root, image=green)
btn_c.bind('<Button-1>', click_c)
btn_c.pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't have to use `lambda` for positional arguments. You can supply them as arguments to `after` (eg: `after(2000, some_function, arg1, arg2)`)

Comment: @BryanOakley I was not aware of that. Thanks for the info. I was under the impression that lambda was the only options if arguments were needed. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you both! My sample code for the question didn't have arguments but my actual program did. Both are working now.

Comment: @Ash.notKetchum good to know your main code had arguments. That is an important bit of info.